# Firestore collectionGroup PERMISSION_DENIED on Android Client

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Testing Collection Group following the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules)

Firestore Security Rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /forums/{forumid}/posts/{post} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Query On Android App (Using Firestore 19.0.1)

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collectionGroup("posts").get().addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
    Log.d(TAG, "queryDocumentSnapshots " + queryDocumentSnapshots.size())

}.addOnFailureListener {
    Log.d(TAG, "exception" + it)
}
```

getting exception PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 19):

You need to add a wild card variable in the path to make it work for collection group queries.
Reference to documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For those looking for docs like me: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups - don't forget the rules_version at the top of the file (as EdwinLiu shows in his example)